# Magento 1.9.3.8 Redis version

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, cache, full-page-cache, redis

I am using Magento 1.9.3.8 with Redis 3.0.6 as backend cache and also my FPC extension is using it for storing files.

I am wondering if Magento is still working with latest Redis 5?
I can't find anything for this